# Unable to create Web application in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, web-application

I'm working on SharePoint 2010 environment.

I'm trying to create new web application.

but it shows error like below

[image]

Please suggest something

Comment: Can you see in event  viewer for any particular log added while this error occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating the web application using Powershell as below:

```
New-SPWebApplication -Name "Contoso Internet Site" -Port 80 -HostHeader sharepoint.contoso.com -URL "https://www.contoso.com" -ApplicationPool "ContosoAppPool" -ApplicationPoolAccount (Get-SPManagedAccount "DOMAIN\jdoe")
```

[New-Spwebapplication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607931.aspx)

I had faced this issue some time back when trying to create a web application using Central Admin UI. So, as M. Qassas correctly mentioned, that changing registry keys is extremely dangerous. I created the web app using the powershell, it took some around 15-20 mins, but the web app was created successfully.

Comment: hi Gautam,  the code  provided by you is a working code in PS ? if i am not using hostheader, what changes need to added/removed?

Comment: Yes its working code, you can remove the hostheader parameter from the command. The only thing that is required is Name and ApplicationPool. The code would be somewhat as below:

`New-SPWebApplication -Name "Contoso Internet Site" -Port 1234 -ApplicationPool "ContosoAppPool" -ApplicationPoolAccount (Get-SPManagedAccount "DOMAIN\jdoe")`

Comment: i have tried to create a web appln using the PS , by following the link : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rcormier/2012/09/01/how-to-create-sharepoint-web-applications-with-powershell/  , but due to some changes in SP 2010 / SP 2013 arch or something, it ddint work for me.  may be because of get-spmanagedaccount command throws an error , if am not wrong.  Thats why I asked the doubt. Thanks , lemme also try to create a  web appln with your code , and update here .Because this code is critical when we create web apps in a prod/ pre-prod/ staging/dev env at on shot!

Comment: Cant we create a application pool is IIS, using a different powershell API, i think , we need to create that apppool, separately. i remember creating the apppool , but thats also was stuck with some errors. with a  specific .net framework ..etc etc

Comment: Check this link to create application pool - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30904.sharepoint-2013-working-with-web-application-pools-adding-removing-and-modifying.aspx , will help you create application pool.

Comment: am getting the   message when i try to create a web app using powershell :  add-pssnapin "microsoft.sharepoint.powershell"
New-SPWebApplication -Name "NPD QA" -Port 28516 -ApplicationPool "NPD_INT_28516_AppPool" -ApplicationPoolAccount (Get-SPManagedAccount "domain1\myusrname")
WARNING: The Windows Classic authentication method is deprecated in this release and the default behavior of this cmdlet, which creates Windows Classic based web application, is obsolete.
It is recommended to use Claims authentication methods. You can
e in the future release to create a Claims authentication

Comment: It is recommended to use Claims authentication methods.
 You can create a web application that uses Claims authentication method by specifying the AuthenticationProvider paramet
er set in this cmdlet. Refer to the http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234549 site for more information.
 Please note that the default behavior of this cmdlet is expected to chang
e in the future release to create a Claims authentication based web application instead of a Windows Classic based web application.

Comment: WARNING: The Windows Classic authentication method is deprecated in this release and the default behavior of this cmdlet, which creates Windows Classic based web application, is obso
lete.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's a Kerberos authentication issue that occurs when setting `Authentication Provider to (Negotiate)`. so try to select `NTLM` and check if it is working.

Another reason, the IIS need to be configured to accept larger headers in the registry. MS KB article explains all those settings: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820129

To Configure IIS to accept larger headers, You will need to adjust The `MaxRequestBytes` and `MaxFieldLength` registry keys to in the registry at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\
```

- MaxFieldLength

  - Default Value: 16384
  - Min – Max Value to set: 64 – 65534 (64kb) bytes
  - Sets an upper limit for each header. See MaxRequestBytes. This limit translates to approximately 32k characters for an URL.
- MaxRequestBytes

  - Default value: 16384
  - Min-Max value to set: 256 – 16777216 (16MB) bytes
  - Determines the upper limit for the total size of the Request line and the headers. Its default setting is 16KB. If this value is lower than MaxFieldLength, the MaxFieldLength value is adjusted.

**Note:** Changing these registry keys can be considered extremely dangerous. These keys allow larger HTTP packets to be sent to IIS, which in turn may cause Http.sys to use more memory and may increase vulnerability to malicious attacks.

For more details check

- ["HTTP 400 - Bad Request (Request Header too long)" error in Internet Information Services (IIS)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2020943/-http-400---bad-request-request-header-too-long-error-in-internet-information-services-iis)
- [Kerberos Authentication Problem with Active Directory](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/surama/2009/04/06/kerberos-authentication-problem-with-active-directory/)